# Get innerHTML without using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I know `innerHTML` is supposed to be icky (and let's not start a debate. We're trying to phase it out at my work), but I need to be able to get the plaintext version of some HTML. Right now I have the lines...

```
bodycontents = document.getElementById("renderzone").innerHTML;
```

But I am wondering exactly how I would, say, get the same result WITHOUT `innerHTML`. I am not afraid of DOM manipulation (I've done a ton of it), so please feel free to be as technical in your answer as you need to be.

Comment: {Groan} "I want to walk, but not using my legs. Please help!"

Comment: let's not start a debate? How about why is there a debate to begin with? What you are trying to do is available through a property called innerHTML. Let's file this under 'first world problems'

Comment: Since innerHTML is the method for getting the HTML contents of an object, please explain why you don't want to use that.  Then, we might have a better idea what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @user why do you not want to use `innerHTML`? Why are you trying to phase it out? Is there some misconception about why it's not  good to use innerHTML? Before you  answer that, I see no point in dealing with this question at all.  Like JohnFx says, it's like wanting to walk but not wanting to use legs for it.

Comment: I don't make the decisions, contrary to what you might have implied by "at my work"

Comment: @user fair enough :) Although I sense a [DailyWTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com) in the making here.

Comment: I've heard some debate saying that *setting* via innerHTML is "icky" but never mention of *getting* innerHTML being bad. Perhaps whoever decided to institute that policy is misinformed.

Comment: I like the option in the deleted answer, using jQuery's element.html() method. Sure, it's just a wrapper for innerHTML, but the prohibition on innerHTML doesn't make sense so why should the workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving an elements inner HTML content without using the `element.innerHTML` attribute sounds like an academic pursuit that isn't likely to have a simple solution.

A DOM based approach would require something like recursively walking to retrieve all child nodes and append their text content and serialize the element name and attributes.  For example (in JavaScript/DOM *pseudo-code*):

```
var getHtmlContent(el, str) {
  str += '<' + el.nodeName;
  foreach (attr in el.attribute) {
    str += attr.name + '="' + escapeAttrVal(attr.value) + '"';
  }
  str += '>';
  foreach (node in el.childNodes) {
    if (node.isTextNode()) {
      str += node.textContent;
    } else {
      str += getHtmlContent(node, str);
    }
  }
  str += '</' + el.nodeName + '>';
  return str;
}
getHtmlContent(myElement, ''); // '<div id="myElement" class="foo">Text<div...'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
someElement.textContent
```

Comment: But `textContent`'s result does not equal `innerHTML`, does it?

Comment: @Pekka "*but I need to be able to get the plaintext version of some HTML*" - as I understand this, OP want's the text content, not the HTML source code...

Comment: Does it really matter...? I'm setting up a CMS email template builder.

Comment: @user It matters because there are some applications where using innerHTML is OK, and there are other applications where innerHTML should be avoided in favor of other techniques. If you don't explain your situation, we are not able to give you advice on whether or not you should be using innerHTML. Could you elaborate? (update your question)

Answer (score 0):

On modern browser the `XMLSerializer` may help you:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('my-id');
var html_string = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(el);
console.log(html_string);
```

```html
<p id="my-id">Greetings Friends</p>
```